# The condition for the equations $\vec r \times \vec a=\vec b$ and $\vec r \times \vec c=\vec d$ to be consistent is?

Tags: vectors

This is an MCQ type question

A) $\vec b.\vec c=\vec a.\vec d$

B) $\vec a. \vec b =\vec c. \vec d$

C) $\vec b.\vec c+\vec a. \vec d=0$

D) $\vec a. \vec b +\vec c.\vec d =0$

Since $\vec a$ is perpendicular to $\vec b$ and same for c and d, both options B and D can be correct.

But surprisingly, the correct answer is option C

I don’t how that is possible. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reasons to why only $B$ and $D$ being true doesn't necessarily prove that the equations hold.

$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = \vec{c}\cdot\vec{d} $ doesn't necessarily mean they're equal to zero.

Similarly, $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} $ can be any non-zero scalar $k$ and $\vec{c}\cdot\vec{d} = -k$. They both add to zero, but individually non-zero.

---

Now, $\vec{c}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{a}) = [ \vec c \ \vec r \ \vec a] = \vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}$
and $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{r}\times\vec{c}) = [ \vec a \ \vec r \ \vec c] = - [ \vec c \ \vec r \ \vec a] = \vec{a}\cdot\vec{d} = -\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c}$.

So, $\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c} + \vec{a}\cdot\vec{d}=0$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $a.(r \times c) = -c.(r \times a)$ look up triple scalar product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product